# Not able to read charts in Google spreadsheet using Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having sheets and charts together in a Google spreadsheet. when I tried to read the sheets using Google app script. I am getting only sheets. Its not even recognizing the charts.

Please let me know how to read the chart?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code to get the [charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()) in the sheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var charts = sheet.getCharts();

 for (var i in charts) {
   var chart = charts[i];
   // Do something with the chart
 }
```

Hope that helps!